# How to delete D drive encrypted by Bitlocker without password or recovery key?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

There's a Dell PC running Windows 10 in my office that a previous user had that they created an encrypted D drive with Bitlocker. The guy has left and nobody has proper contact with them.

I don't care about the data on the D drive I just want to delete the drive off the PC. Steps I have already taken are:

- Reinstall Windows
- Reset the PC with the options "Remove everything" and "Only drives where windows is installed"

When I chose the option "All drives" I get an error saying "There was a problem resetting your PC".

Can anyone provide instructions on how to delete the D drive encrypted with Bitlocker?

Comment: D: drive? What drive is that? Is there a USB drive plugged in or some secondary drive in the computer? Sounds like he may have repartitioned the hard drive and made a second partition. Just go in to disk management and delete the D: partition and extend the C: drive. If you’re just trying to reinstall Windows you can do that during windows setup as well. Boot the setup disk, then delete all partitions off the drive before proceeding, when Windows asks you where to install.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you should be able to just delete the partition using any disk partitioning tool.

If Windows' built-in tools (diskmgmt.msc, diskpart) do not work then you can boot a Linux live system from CD or USB stick – such as Ubuntu or GParted Live – and use the "GParted" tool.